# Glib - interrupt foreach

Tags: foreach, glib

I have very long collection - GList (huge amount of samples). For validation of every sample I am using g_list_foreach. The processing of the whole list lasts long. Sometimes it would be very useful to interrupt processing (via system signal SIGINT). Is there any way to interrupt foreach function?

Answer (score 2):

It's trivial to implement something like `g_list_foreach` which would check a flag on each iteration, then you just need to install a signal handler to set the flag.

Here is [the entire implementation of `g_list_foreach`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/glist.c?id=a4fc4c1e6eb57b10e2b60f522d11fd2c256dee31#n984):

```
void
g_list_foreach (GList    *list,
                GFunc     func,
                gpointer  user_data)
{
  while (list)
    {
      GList *next = list->next;
      (*func) (list->data, user_data);
      list = next;
    }
}
```

How to install the handler will depend on how you want to structure your application, but if nothing else you could use a [GOnce](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#GOnce) to install the handler, so something like:

```
static volatile gboolean my_flag = FALSE;

static void
handle_sigint(int id) {
  my_flag = TRUE;
}

static gpointer
install_handler(gpointer data)
{
  signal(SIGINT, handle_sigint);
  return NULL;
}

/* Returns FALSE if interrupted, TRUE otherwise. */
gboolean
my_g_list_foreach (GList    *list,
                   GFunc     func,
                   gpointer  user_data)
{
  static GOnce handler_once = G_ONCE_INIT;
  g_once(&handler_once, install_handler, NULL);

  my_flag = FALSE;

  while (list)
    {
      if (flag)
        return FALSE;

      GList *next = list->next;
      (*func) (list->data, user_data);
      list = next;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```